# UVM : How to connect multi dimensional arrays in virtual interface?

Tags: arrays, verilog, system-verilog, uvm

I have 5 SRAM instances (== 5 different 2-D arrays) in DUT (all in verilog). I want to do backdoor loading on these arrays from a UVM testbench. There are multiple drivers on SRAM array, either from DUT itself or from testbench (from testbench it is mainly backdoor access using $readmemh).
Now, i wanted a handle of these arrays into UVM testbench. So, i created a virtual interface which has local memory array and instantiated the interface 5 times. 
Trouble is, how to connect DUT SRAM array with the array in virtual interface? I need to make a weak connection so that there is no contention when DUT drives the array.

Can anyone suggest how to connect multi dimensional arrays in UVM testbench and not have strong drivers?

Comment: It might be helpful to add some code to the question. How does your interface look like? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Since the was no Code, it was a bit hard to understand the question.

My understanding is that you are trying to initialize several 2D array. In case you are using Modelsim, there is a very simple way for initialization through TCL scripts. Indeed this tool considers all 2D array as memory and it has a TCL function to load a contents from file to these memory arrays.

Here is an example of the TCL code to do so:

mem load -i Startup_Memories/sram.hex -format hex -fillradix symbolic -skip 0 /orpsoc_testbench/dut/ram_wb0/ram_wb_b3_0/ram0